# Multiple console commands with py2exe

Tags: python, windows, python-2.x, py2exe, python-packaging

My current `setup.py` has three `console_scripts` entries:

```
console_scripts=[
    ‘myapp-dev=bin/run:dev',
    ‘myapp=bin/run:prod',
    ‘myapp-cmd-line=bin/run:cmd'
]
```

`run.py` contains trivial functions for these:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

myapp = App()

def dev():
    myapp.run(mode='dev')

def prod():
    myapp.run()

def cmdline():
    myapp.run(mode='cmd')
```

Is there a way I can create 3 separate `.exe` files for each of the above